# incorrect implementation of in-app billing

Tags: android, android-security

I just received the following email from Google Play

We detected that your app(s) listed at the end of this email are invoking the in-app billing service without setting a target package for the intent. This can enable a malicious package to bypass the Play store billing system and access items that have not been purchased.

Next Steps:

1. If you are using IabHelper, please start using the latest SDK.
2. If you are manually invoking the in-app billing service, make sure you are calling `Intent.setPackage(“com.android.vending”)` on any intents to `com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND`.
3. Sign in to your Developer Console and submit the updated version of your app.
4. Check back after five hours - we’ll show a warning message if the app hasn’t been updated correctly.
   We’re here to help

I use the IabHelper, but not the latest SDK. My App always has this in place, but I still received the warning.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: And what's the question? -> If you are using IabHelper, please start using the latest SDK

Comment: Although I don't use the latest SDK,but the old SDK has below code in place.Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

Comment: I think this is send to all old in-app users. i also recently got this message.